# Integer division not producing expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x

The question I attempted to answer is as follows: Write a Python function that computes the number of days, hours, and minutes in a given number of minutes

ie: `def daysHoursMinutes(m)`: which ends as returns `(d, h, M)`

I wrote the following code:

```
def daysHoursMinutes(m):
    import math
    d=m/1440 #integer
    h=m/60  #integer
    M=m     #integer
    return(d,h,M)
```

and when I input in `daysHoursMinutes(241)` what im expecting to get is `(0,4,1)`, but I get `((0.1673611111111111, 4.016666666666667, 241)`.  I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

[Integer division in Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv) uses `//` like:

#### Code:

```
def daysHoursMinutes(m):
    d = m // 1440
    m -= d * 1440
    h = m // 60
    m -= h * 60
    return d, h, m
```

#### Test Code:

```
print(daysHoursMinutes(241))
```

#### Results:

```
(0, 4, 1)
```